# jwPlayer 6 seeking to exact position

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza, m3u8

Is it possible to somehow get jwPlayer 6 to seek to an exact position in the video, regardless of keyframe interval?

I acknowledge that this probably requires that it will have to go to the previous key frame and load from there, but I want it to skip those few seconds and only start exactly at the second I specify.

We're currently using Wowza for streaming.

If the response involves injecting a keyframe at the position I want it - are there any tools that can do that for mp4-videos? e.g "promotetokeyframe videofile.mp4 12.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use our API and jwplayer().seek(); but we do only seek to available keyframes. The API reference is here, in case you need it - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: Thank you, but that does not solve my requirement. I'd like to seek to an exact timestamp, even if jwPlayer has to "virtualy play" a couple of seconds while hiding the video.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. I wish it was possible to seek to an exact position without adding more keyframes. I guess I can hide the player using Javascript while it is playing the "unwanted" couple of seconds before the requested position.